# Обновление сайта на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, seo, оптимизация-сайтов, поисковые-системы

есть сайт на котором нужно обновить тему, провести оптимизацию и чистку большого количества медиа файлов, удалить ненужные файлы и тд. Это всё удобнее всего делать на локальном сервере, экспортировав весь сайт, а после всех изменений перенести обратно на хастинг, удалив старый.
Собственно вопрос заключается в том, ухудшится ли сео сайта и его позиция в выдаче (над сео когда то работала студия), при том что все ссылки, названия файлов и тд останутся такими же?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Это всё удобнее всего делать на локальном сервере

Насчёт удобнее - вопрос спорный. Но правильнее - однозначно на том же сервере. На др. домене, с закрытым извне доступом.
См так же [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress/767562#767562)

> ухудшится ли сео сайта и его позиция в выдаче (над сео когда то
>   работала студия), при том что все ссылки, названия файлов и тд
>   останутся такими же?

Если не накосячить, то с чего бы?

Comment: Спасибо за совет, я использую duplicator pro, по идее проблем с путями быть не должно. Но я все равно не очень понимаю разницы переноса с локалки или с другого домена, это же все равно получается как разные сайты и в конце всё равно нужно будет старый полностью заменять на новый, нет?

Comment: @DenisPenkov "Локалка" - это форки вебсервера (набора линксвского ПО) на виндовсе же? А это другая ОС, другие правила, половина работает не так. Даже на др хостинге - и то возможны различные неожиданности из-за разного серверного ПО и его настроек, а уж виндовс... Поэтому я и настоятельно рекомендую использовать тот же хостинг. А кроме переноса ещё и др моменты в разработке - напр. возможность тестирования и ловли ошибок. В другой среде всё по другому и по сути бесполезно (а то и вредно).

Answer (score 0):

WordPress очень плохо переносит замену или перенос файлов, поэтому делайте лучше на  том же сервере...

По второму вопросу: Однозначно Нет! (Если все сделать правильно ; )

Comment: Все он нормально переносит. Делать надо правильно. Посмотрите ссылку на мой ответ в соседнем ответе. Я эти сайты таскаю туда-сюда по 10 раз на дню.

Comment: @KAGGDesign разные пейджбилдеры и ревослайдеры/несктгаллереи такого напихают, что дубликатор не находит Я сталкивался. Вот поперепроверяй  пути после миграции поиском по базе. Вспомню плаг из репо который тоже ломается тк его работу дуликатор не видит - напишу в слак, посмотришь :)

Comment: @SeVlad с Visual Composer проблем не встречал, как и с Elementor. Пару раз что-то было с LayerSlider, да. Но в 99% случаев - всё ок с Duplicator.