# Как отключить редирект с http на https в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, ssl

Перенес для разработки сайт с хостинга на локальный.

Там он с https, а на локальном надо http.

1. В админке в settings->general стоит http
2. В таблице wp-option siteurl и home - http
3. htaccess закомментирован
4. По всем таблицам https заменил на http
5. Использовал 4 браузера, из которых не ходил на сайт

Все-равно, редиректит на https.

Что делать, уже не знаю, второй день борюсь.

Помогите, кто знает.

Answer (score 1):

> По всем таблицам https заменил на http

Напрямую в базе? Значит поломал сайт. Да собсно поломал его раньше неправильным  переносом.  См [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress/767562#767562)

А вообще не используй "локальный". См рядом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863450.

Comment: перенес с помощью migrate db, но редирект все-равно никуда не делся.

Comment: Редирект может кешироваться в браузере. Проверяй внешними сервисами. Напр https://bertal.ru/ А может быть прописан в htaccess, Или запись в hosts, если таки "лоальный". Или же не всё поменял в базе.

Comment: Так и не поборол, а за ресурс спасибо.

Comment: @Сергей ну если внешний сервис показывает редирект - ищи в файлах, базе, настройках хостинга.